# BFG - Is there any way to replace text on files on a specific path?

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

I'm using BFG to cleanup a repository removing some sensitive data from files.

The command I'm running looks like this:

```
java -jar bfg --replace-text passwords.txt -fi '*.config' repo.git
```

The issue is that the repository has several *.config* files but I only want to make the changes on the ones that are in a specific path.

Is that possible?